# Opening CSV in Numbers does not display decimal numbers correctly

Tags: numbers, csv

Lets say I have following CSV file:

```
1.0;0.125;0.1253
```

Opening it in Numbers gives me:

[image]

Why are 1.0 and 0.1253 correctly presented as "1.0" and "0.1253", but "0.125" is presented as "125"?

What do I have to do to get Numbers to display "0.125" correctly?

---

Edit: My region and language settings are set to Europe/Germany.

Comment: Your test CSV works correctly in Numbers (for me).  What are your macOS language settings?

Comment: @Gilby My region and language settings are set to Europe/Germany. I have added this as a note to the question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Numbers is recognizing the dot as a thousands separator rather than a decimal point when a decimal has a sole leading zero and exactly three digits after the decimal point.

As a workaround, you can instruct Numbers to treat all dots as decimal points. To do that, use the Numbers' import settings menu which you can reach by clicking on the "Table data was imported and can be adjusted. >" popup warning that would appear right after a text or CSV files is opened by Numbers.

Then, in Import Settings, go to Advanced Settings and enter `.` for the Decimal Separator option and click on Update Table.

You can reach Import Settings also through the "Adjust Import Settings..." option at the bottom of the Format->Table sidebar.

Another option is to remove all the sole leading zeros from all decimal points in the CSV file, i.e. use `.125` instead of `0.125` or `.3` instead of `0.3`.

---

**UPDATE**

This happens because your macOS Region setting is Germany and, for Germany, the default Number format under System Settings -> General -> Language & Region is `1.234.567,89`. This Number format setting unfortunately causes Numbers to recognize the dot in a decimal with a sole leading zero and exactly three digits after the dot as a thousands separator.

A workaround other than those I suggested earlier would be to change the Number format setting. This can be accomplished by changing the Region from Germany to USA or UK or by only changing the Number format setting to `1,234,567.89` or `1 234 567,89`. In the latter Number format setting, however, as would be with the current setting, all decimals which have the dot as the decimal point would be imported into Numbers as text by default rather than numbers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I'm opening many dozens of CSV file a day, and it is not feasible to do that via explicit import every time. I need to do it via double click. Is it possible to tell Numbers to import everything as pure text? I don't need any kind of fancy processing. All I want is to see the raw data in the CSV.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know at this time how you can make this work without dealing with the import settings in Numbers every time. You may either try another spreadsheet program or if you need to be using Numbers, you might look into preprocessing your CSV files in order to remove the leading sole zeroes in decimals using a macOS command line tool such as `awk`or a programming language like Python.

Comment: On another thought, if viewing the CSV files as pure text is enough for you, why don't you open them using the macOS's text editor, TextEdit, instead of Numbers? In case necessary, you can change the default program for opening text files as described in the "[Choose an app to open a file on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35597/mac)" Apple Support webpage.

Comment: *"This can be accomplished by changing the Region from Germany to USA or UK or by only changing the Number format setting to 1,234,567.89 or 1 234 567,89."* — am I right that these changes would apply system-wide and not only for numbers?

Comment: @theV0ID Yes, for all macOS.